# Check Point: ISP Redundancy Link Interface Cannot Be Created

Tags: networking, firewall, checkpoint

While setting up ISP Redundancy on a Check Point cluster I ran into an issue preventing me from proceeding with my configuration.  I was eventually able to resolve this and felt that I would share with you and my future self the steps taken.

What is ISP Redundancy

ISP Redundancy enables reliable Internet connectivity by allowing a single or clustered Check Point Security Gateway to connect to the Internet via redundant Internet service provider (ISP) connections. If both links are active, connections pass through one link, or both links, depending on the operating mode. If one of the link fails, new connections are handled by the second link.

Configuration Steps

Open the network object properties of the Security Gateway or cluster.
Click Other > ISP Redundancy.
Select Support ISP Redundancy.
Select Load Sharing or Primary/Backup.
Configure Links – Primary and Backup Connections
Set tacking mode for Link failure and recovery
Click OK — This is when I encounter my error

Error: Check Point SmartDashboard

At least one of your ISP Links lack a next hop IP Address configuration.
Note: next hop IP Address is also used to automatically monitor the ISP Link^s availability.

Error: Check Point SmartDashboard

ISP Redundancy configuration on clusters requires that the interfaces which lead to your ISPs, have the same names as the corresponding physical interfaces on the cluster^s members.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution Steps Taken:**

Discovered that the the interfaces in the topology tab did not have the same name on the vip (Virtual IP), so I changed to name so that all interfaces were matching.

After introducing the changes to the interface name of the vip, I retried the setup for ISP Redundancy and the issue resolved.

I shared this on my blog: http://jermsmit.com/isp-redundancy-link-interface-cannot-be-created/